# Azure Data Factory deployed via ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I deploy successfully. The pipeline has a Copy step copying a csv file from a linked storage account to a linked Azure SQL database.
The deployed version fails with "Error 2012,Value cannot be null. Parameter name: dictionary".

I can manually rebuild the Copy and it works fine but I cannot determine how to fix my template. I've tried exporting the successful run and looking at the code via {}, but so far no luck.

Comment: Can you show the arm template?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Sp_8OLWcgQUqqyrhEh28JMrTrjKynM0-?usp=sharing

Comment: Posted a Google Drive link that should be public. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the Linked AzureSqlDatabase service, typeProperties contained a Connection String and "type": "SecureString". I'm not sure why that was ever inserted. However, the fact that the LinkedService connection tested successfully, made me ignore the connection string.

Once I detected its presence and removed it, all worked properly.