# Error to update table in oracle with Datafactory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I must update a table in oracle from datafactory, I am doing it with the lookup activity but it fails, however the record is updated, the error is the following;
[image]

this is the update  code:

[image]

Any ideas or advice, I will be very grateful

Comment: The exception that is thrown when a null reference (not set or empty) is passed to a method that does not accept it as a valid argument. 

You can find more information refer-http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~lok/csharp/refdocs/System/types/ArgumentNullException.html

Also refer this link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63182755/azure-data-factory-deployed-via-arm-template

If this does not work, please provide oracle table schema.

Comment: The error comes out because the lookup activity expects a response when an update is made, an attempt has been made to execute the FOR i IN command l_tab.first .. l_tab.last LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('UPDATE IBCSIC =' || l_tab (i));
   END LOOP;

but nothing returned in datafactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this type of scenario is to perform the update through the copy activity and on the sink side using Pre-copy script and on the source side a select statement must be executed that does not return any data and therefore no data is written in the destination table.

in this way it is not necessary to wait for the update to return some data, what if it happens when using look up activity